# Newline character in bing translation text

Tags: java, bing-api

This is a very basic question

I am using the Bing translate API method: Translate.execute(String to be translated,Target Language)
When there is no newline character in the source language then it is all fine. E.g.

```
String str = "I have seen some app. Educational and fun.";
```

But If my source text has multiple lines and looks like following, how do I create a String variable for it:

```
I have seen some app.
Educational and fun.
```

I don't want to add /n, /r characters inside my string because the bing API will try to translate these characters also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you instead translate each sentence or line at a time and combine them after the fact?

```
String str1 = "I have seen some app.";
String str2 = "Educational and fun.";

String result = Translate.execute(str1) + "\n" + Translate.execute(str2);
```

Or translate it all at once and add the newlines characters in after you get the translation back? Maybe something like (may be too simplistic):

```
String str = "I have seen some app. Educational and fun.";
String result = Translate.execute(str);
result = result.replaceAll(".", "\n");
```